# How can I scrape from a webpage that uses javascript to load in elements as you scroll?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

My friend asked if I could write a web scraping script to collect data of pokemon from a specific website.

I've written the following code to render the javascript and get a particular class to collect data from the website (https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/pokemon/).

**The issue is**, the page loads more entries as you scroll down the page. Is there any way of scraping from this? I'm new to web scraping so I'm not entirely sure how this all works.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def getPokemon(link):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(link)
    r.html.render()
    for pokemon in r.html.find("div.PokemonAltRow"):
        print(pokemon)
    quit()

getPokemon('https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/pokemon/')
```

Comment: You can achieve this using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is actually present in the page source. See `view-source:https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/pokemon/` (It is present inside on the script tag as a javascript variable).

```
import requests
import re
import json


response = requests.get('https://www.smogon.com/dex/ss/pokemon/')

# The following regex will help you take the json string from the response text
data = "".join(re.findall(r'dexSettings = (\{.*\})', response.text))

# the above will only return a string, we need to parse that to json in order to process it as a regular json object using `json.loads()`
data = json.loads(data)

# now we can query json string like below.
data = data.get('injectRpcs', [])[1][1].get('items', [])

for row in data:
  print(row.get('name', ''))
  print(row.get('description', ''))
```

See it in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/AcademicRelevantSource)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, much neater than what I was writing! I was aware it was in the source of the page but wondered if it was possible to scrape from the page by loading all of the javascript. I guess that's just unnecessarily overcomplicating it though.