# Not able to scrape div tags from this html

Tags: python

Attempting to do some web scraping on this page and not getting any div tags:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
my_url = 'https://www.smogon.com/dex/rb/pokemon/'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#html parse
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs Pokemon
pokemon = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"PokemonAltRow"})
```

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Which fragment in the retrieved HTML do you expect to match?

Comment: You have to describe your symptoms properly verbally: *"Not able to strip html"* and *" I am getting nothing in return."* do not tell us anything. Presumably your scraping `.findAll()` is returning empty list.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot find the `divs` you are looking for because they are dynamically loaded with javascript. Your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60017438/how-can-i-scrape-from-a-webpage-that-uses-javascript-to-load-in-elements-as-you)